# Problem with solving a complicated Integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I need to determine the $ \int \frac{\sin^3(x)}{8-\cos^3(x)} dx$. It's an indefinite integral.

Comment: What are the limits? Or do you mean indefinite integral?

Comment: I meant indefinite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\sin^3(x) = \sin(x)(\sin^2(x)) = \sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))$

Take $u = \cos(x) \Rightarrow du = -\sin(x) \ dx$

So we have, $- \int \frac{1-u^2}{8-u^3} du = -\int \frac{1}{8-u^3} du - \int \frac{u^2}{8-u^3} du $

Comment: Ahhhh okok thanks a lot!!

Comment: If your satisfied with this would you mind checking it off? :)

Comment: Actually I never learned how to integrate these two functions... I only learned to integrate 1/(a^2+u^2)

Comment: Now you have to do partial fractions.

Comment: I've been doing it for a while but I just can't seem to be doing it right